# Proving that if $a^3=b^3\rightarrow a=b$ using only field axioms.

Tags: axioms

How can I prove that if $a^3=b^3\rightarrow a=b$  using only field axioms $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

I feel like it has something to do with
$$
a^3-b^3=0\rightarrow a^3+(-a^3)=0 \rightarrow -b^3=(-a^3)
$$
but I have no clue how to continue the proof.

I am also not sure if it's possible to say that
$$
a^3-b^3=(a - b)\cdot(a^2 + ab + b^2)
$$
because I am restricted to prove this with field axioms only.

Comment: You can't do that using only field axioms since there are fields (such as $\Bbb C$) for which that assertion is false. But it is true for every *ordered* field.

Comment: Your second equation is easy to prove though, just expand the product ...

Comment: @LL3.14 I realize that but to be able to use the second equation I would have to prove that $a^3-b^3=(a-b)\cdot(a^2+ab+b^2)$ which would probably be the easiest way to go right?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

According to Newton's binomial formula, one has:
\begin{align*}
(a - b)^{3} & = a^{3} - 3a^{2}b + 3ab^{2} - b^{3} = (a^{3} - b^{3}) - 3ab(a - b)
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that
\begin{align*}
a^{3} - b^{3} & = (a - b)^{3} + 3ab(a - b)\\\\
& = (a - b)[(a - b)^{2} + 3ab]\\\\
& = (a - b)(a^{2} + ab + b^{2})
\end{align*}

As @JoséCarlosSantos has mentioned, it is necessary to consider the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is linearly ordered (which means that it is a partially ordered set and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ are always comparable):
\begin{align*}
a^{2} + ab + b^{2} & = \left(a^{2} + ab + \frac{b^{2}}{4}\right) + \frac{3b^{2}}{4}\\\\
& = \left(a + \frac{b}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{3b^{2}}{4} \geq 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Using Newton's binomial formula seems a bit overkill since then one could also directly use the identity for $a^3-b^3$ ... the formula for $a^3-b^3$ can be obtained very easily from fields axiom by expanding $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. For the other part, I agree :)

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks for the feedback :)